# Which version of ubuntu I can/should install to my computer?

Tags: cpu

My computer has Intel(R)Pentium(R)CPU2117U@1.80GHz processor, 4GB RAM, 64bit

Comment: Personally I'd decide on far more than base specs of the machine, as that makes up maybe 25-30% of what matters in the decision in my opinion... ie. I'd consider the apps you'll run, your tastes as for desktop firstly... let alone your preferences for newer software, willingness to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months or prefer to do that 2-3 yearly... as the cpu/RAM is only a small part of the important detail.

Comment: FYI:  I QA-test using a box from 2005 and it will run all; though until recently it had an nvidia card that would steer me heavily towards some choices and away from others (*you didn't mention GPU!*) but I replaced that video card to avoid that issue (*it was kernel module related & some releases have more choice than others..*)  ie. you need to consider more than just what you provided; but you test it before you install & get a pretty good idea - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install which works with all *flavors* of Ubuntu too.